# question about  application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a table in my application.html.erb.like this:

```
<body>
<table width='100%' border='3'>
  <tr><td height="100"> </td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%"></td>
    <td width="80%"></td>
    <td width="10%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<%= yield %>

</body>
```

i want to put contents of other page in `<td width="80%"></td>` but i dont know how can i do that?
thank you for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
<table width='100%' border='3'>
  <tr><td height="100"> </td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%"></td>
    <td width="80%"><%= render "other_page" %></td>
    <td width="10%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<%= yield %>

</body>
```

This will render `_other_page.html.erb`.

Read more about it here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 1):

Simply move the `yield` statement:

```
<body>
  <table width='100%' border='3'>
    <tr>
      <td height="100"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10%"></td>
      <td width="80%"><%= yield %></td>
      <td width="10%"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```